# Null while there should be a value, how to solve this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, identity

Have a problem that result is null while result1 has a good value.

```
IdentityRole result1 = roleTable.GetRoleByName(roleName);
TRole result = result1 as TRole;
```

My class is defined like this:

```
public class RoleStore<TRole> : IQueryableRoleStore<TRole>
where TRole : IdentityRole
```

And the whole function:

```
public Task<TRole> FindByNameAsync(string roleName)
        {
            IdentityRole result1 = roleTable.GetRoleByName(roleName);
            TRole result = result1 as TRole;
            return Task.FromResult<TRole>(result);
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us how do you create an instance of `RoleStore`?

Comment: That just looks like your TRole and type of result1 are not implicitely convertable, and are different implementations of IdentityRole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand from your code is that TRole descends from IdentityRole. That would make TRole an IdentityRole at all times but not the other way around. So result1 is not a TRole.

GetRoleByName may however return a TRole. If you know that to be the case, just declare result1 to be a TRole instead.

But apparently GetRoleByName does not return a TRole. If it did your code, beit odd, should have succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

You use operator `as` to casting type

```
TRole result = result1 as TRole;
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx):

> The `as` operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion
>   isn't possible, as returns `null` instead of raising an exception.

So, it means that cast the `IdentityRole` to `TRole`  is not possible